# What is wrong with my method of solving $\int { 7tsin^2(t) dt} $?

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral:

$$\int { 7t\sin^2(t) dt} $$

What I did:

$$\int { 7t\sin^{ 2 }(t)dt } =7\int { t\sin^{ 2 }(t)dt } $$

$$=7\int { t\frac { 1 }{ 2 } (1-\cos(2t))dt } $$

$$=7\int { (\frac { t }{ 2 } -\frac { t }{ 2 } \cos(2t))dt } $$

$$=7\int { \frac { t }{ 2 } dt } -7\int { \frac { t }{ 2 } \cos(2t))dt } $$

$$=\frac { 7 }{ 2 } \int { tdt } -\frac { 7 }{ 2 } \int { t\cos(2t)dt } $$

We evaluate the integral on the left hand side and we create the substitution $u=2t$ and $du=2dt$ and get:

$$\frac { 7t^{ 2 } }{ 4 } +C-\frac { 7 }{ 4 } \int { t\cos(2t)dt } =\frac { 7t^{ 2 } }{ 4 } -\frac { 7 }{ 4 } [\sin(u)]+C$$

Finally, we get:

$$\frac { 7t^{ 2 } }{ 4 } -\frac { 7 }{ 4 } \sin(2t)+C$$

This is wrong according to wolfram alpha, but I don't understand why. I would appreciate some help/guidance.

Comment: @AlexSilva That was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Why $7/2$ becomes $7/4$?

Comment: Note $\int t\cos(2t) dt = \frac{1}{4} \int u\cos u du$. At some point you need to do integration by part

Comment: it must be $$7\,t \left( -1/2\,\cos \left( t \right) \sin \left( t \right) +t/2
 \right) +7/4\, \left( \sin \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}-7/4\,{t}^{2
}
$$

Comment: What are you doing to get rid of that t sitting in front of $t cos 2t$?  You are going to need integration by parts...

Comment: @JohnMa I think I got it, thanks to you. Starting from the last step I did before I mistakenly substituted:

$=\frac { 7t^{ 2 } }{ 4 } -\frac { 7 }{ 2 } [t\cdot \frac { 1 }{ 2 } sin(2t)-\int { 1\cdot \frac { 1 }{ 2 } sin(2t)dt } ]$ then, $=\frac { 7t^{ 2 } }{ 4 } -\frac { 7 }{ 4 } [t\cdot sin(2t)+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } cos(2t)]+C$, and finally $=\frac { 7t^{ 2 } }{ 4 } -\frac { 7t }{ 4 } sin(2t)-\frac { 7 }{ 8 } cos(2t)+$